# Can not remove underline for a link

Tags: text-decorations

I can not remove the grey line under a link named "click here" on my client’s website about page (http://shop.kariamukreations.com/about). I have set the text-decoration for this link to: none and that did not make it go away. What’s going on? It only goes away if I remove the  tags for "click here".

[image]

Can anyone you solve this for me? Thanks.

Refe

Comment: Welcome to SO. I checked the link you added above and noticed somewhere in your a:link you have had bottom-border. To fix this add border-bottom: none; to the anchor of 'click here'

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me copying the HTML of your page:

```
<a href="mailto:info@kariamukreations.com" style="text-decoration:none;">
```

Maybe other parts of your template/css is overriding this.